# Python itertools combinations on objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, combinations, python-itertools

Can the python itertools combinations library by used on objects rather than lists?

For instance, how may I use it on the following data?

```
Rahul - 20,000 - Mumbai

Shivani - 30,000 - Mumbai

Akash - 40,000 - Bangalore
```

I want all the possible combinations on the names and the combined salary value.

How can I do this with `combinations`?
Assuming the data is read using `pd.read_csv` and is stored.

Code so far -

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
df = pd.read_csv('stack.csv')

print (df)

for L in range(0, len(df)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(df['Name'], L):
        print (subset)
```

Output

```
      Name  Salary       City
0    Rahul   20000     Mumbai
1  Shivani   30000     Mumbai
2    Akash   40000  Bangalore
()
('Rahul',)
('Shivani',)
('Akash',)
('Rahul', 'Shivani')
('Rahul', 'Akash')
('Shivani', 'Akash')
('Rahul', 'Shivani', 'Akash')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I add salary to these combinations?

Comment: Can you print df.head(5) to get an idea of input format?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: Is it any better now?

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want the salaries concatenated with the names (i.e., Rahul always has 20000), or you want combinations of (name, salary, name, salary) (i.e., there are items where Rahul has 20000, 30000, and 40000)?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: The ultimate desired output is that I have a user inputted "Salary" and I want to find the closest salary (combined or individual) to that user Salary. 
So, I guess it would be easier if Rahul always has 20000.

Answer (score 5):

First, get your indices:

```
idx = [j for i in range(1, len(df) + 1) for j in list(itertools.combinations(df.index, i))]
# [(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Get your dataframes for each group:

```
dfs = [df.iloc[list(i)] for i in idx]
```

Finally, join and sum:

```
out = [(', '.join(i.name.values), sum(i.salary.values)) for i in dfs]
```

Output:

```
[('Rahul', 20000),
 ('Shivani', 30000),
 ('Akash', 40000),
 ('Rahul, Shivani', 50000),
 ('Rahul, Akash', 60000),
 ('Shivani, Akash', 70000),
 ('Rahul, Shivani, Akash', 90000)]
```

If you want this as a dataframe, it's quite simple:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['names', 'salaries'])

                   names  salaries
0                  Rahul     20000
1                Shivani     30000
2                  Akash     40000
3         Rahul, Shivani     50000
4           Rahul, Akash     60000
5         Shivani, Akash     70000
6  Rahul, Shivani, Akash     90000
```

To query this dataframe to find the closest value to a given salary, we can write a helper function:

```
def return_closest(val):
    return df1.iloc[(df1.salaries - val).abs().idxmin()]


>>> return_closest(55000)
names       Rahul, Shivani
salaries             50000
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

I intentionally broke this down so you could understand what was going on at each step.  Once you *do* understand, you could combine this into a one-liner to create your dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(', '.join(d.name.values), sum(d.salary.values))
    for i in [j for i in range(1, len(df) + 1)
    for j in list(itertools.combinations(df.index, i))]
    for d in [df.iloc[list(i)]]], columns=['names', 'salaries']
)
```

Comment: The part where you have used join(i.name.values), how may I use it for multiple columns? Assume I want the City to be included in this result, how do I rewrite this line?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `zip` to iterate through both columns at the same time and use a list comprehension to generate the output dataframe such as:

```
df_ouput = pd.DataFrame( [[', '.join(subset), sum(salaries)] for L in range(1, len(df)+1)
                           for subset, salaries in zip(itertools.combinations(df['Name'], L),
                                                       itertools.combinations(df['Salary'], L))], 
                         columns = ['Names','Sum Salaries'])
```

and you get:

```
                   Names  Sum Salaries
0                  Rahul         20000
1                Shivani         30000
2                  Akash         40000
3         Rahul, Shivani         50000
4           Rahul, Akash         60000
5         Shivani, Akash         70000
6  Rahul, Shivani, Akash         90000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this?

```
nameList = list()
sumList = list()
for L in range(0, len(df)+1):
    for x in itertools.combinations(df['Name'], L):
        nameList.append(x)
    for y in itertools.combinations(df['Salary'], L):
        sumList.append(sum(y))

newDf = pd.DataFrame()
newDf['Names'] = nameList
newDf['Salary Sum'] = sumList
```

Output:

```
                     Names  Salary Sum
0                       ()           0
1                 (Rahul,)       20000
2               (Shivani,)       30000
3                 (Akash,)       40000
4         (Rahul, Shivani)       50000
5           (Rahul, Akash)       60000
6         (Shivani, Akash)       70000
7  (Rahul, Shivani, Akash)       90000
```